# Pull img src from this html grabbed with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am extracting an image from a part of the document using:

```
var  theImg = document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML;
```

This returns something like

```
theImg = <img src="http://website.com/image.jpg?&image-presets&" alt="foo" style="z-index: 1" />
```

How could I grab just the src of the image, without the parameter.  So that

`theImg = http://website.com/image.jpg`

I am open to using a regular expression, php, or vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there appear to be no correct and complete answers so far with a working demonstration, I'll attempt one:

```
var imgs = document.getElementById('imageDiv').getElementsByTagName('img');
var theImgSrc = imgs[0].src;
var loc = theImgSrc.indexOf("?");
if (loc != -1) {
    theImgSrc = theImgSrc.substr(0, loc);
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NSczd/

Comment: Just missing the part where you strip the query string.

Comment: It was added while you were typing.  Since there were so many wrong implementations in this thread, I thought I should make sure mine worked by verifying it in a jsFiddle which took a little longer.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but I believe this should do the job.  It first retrieves the image `src` and then strips off everything starting with the `?`.

```
var imgDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv');
var imgs = imgDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
  var theImg = imgs[i].getAttribute('src').substr(0, theImg.indexOf('?'));
  console.log(theImg);
  // Do whatever you need to with theImg. Add to an array or whatever...
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  imageDiv is a containing div, not the image tag itself.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but `imageDiv` doesn't have a `src` it is a div which contains an image.

Comment: Because the code is broken... there is no 'src' attribute on the imageDiv.

Comment: .getAttribute is returning null for me but innerHTML works fine ?

Comment: @jfriend00 @kingjiv I see. Corrected above.

Comment: @Sushi K I made a big correction.  Try the updated code above.

Comment: minor quibble: the `e` in `getElementsByTagName` is lowercase in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `.getAttribute('src')` on the image element itself, and assign that string to theImg.

More fully, the following:

```
var theImg = document.getElementById('your_image').getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: OP is asking to strip off the querystring too.

Comment: Ah, missed that part. Just change your code to `getElementById('your_image')` and yours is best then.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, yeah, this is better.

```
 var theImgSRC = document.getElementById('imageDiv').querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  theImg is a string.  You can't call getElementsByTagName on a string.

Comment: I think you want to remove `innerHTML` because I don't believe you can call `getElementsByTagName` on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Handles both parts of the question:

```
var imgDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv');

var imgs = imgDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");

var url = "";

if (imgs.length > 0) {
    var img = imgs[0];
    var questionIndex = img.src.indexOf("?");

    if (questionIndex > -1) {
        url = img.src.substring(0, questionIndex);
    } else {
        url = img.src;
    }
}

alert(url);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cvhwZ/2/

Answer (score -1):

```
 document.getElementById('imageDiv').querySelector("img").getAttribute('src').theImg.substr(0, theImg.indexOf('?'));
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I was wrong originally but I think my modified answer is sufficient.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this won't work in IE6 or IE7 because querySelectorAll is not supported.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Damn. I think I'm just gonna stop supporting IE users soon.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the OP is asking to strip off the querystring too.

Comment: And besides, if you're using the much newer, nicer querySelector, you might as well just use `querySelector('#imageDiv img')`. Also, querySelectorAll is wrong in the first place because it returns a list. Remove the All and you're fine.

Comment: Gah, need to work on my javascript. This would have been a lot easier with jQuery. :P